# Is the derived category of a commutative ring monoidal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and consider the derived category $D(A)$.

1. Is this a symmetric monoidal category? We have an obvious product, that is $-\otimes^L_A - $, and it is clear that we have an associator, that is, an isomorphism $(M\otimes^L_A N)\otimes^L_A K \cong M\otimes^L_A (N\otimes^L_A K)$. However, for this to be a monoidal category, we need that the pentagon diagram (the two ways to get associativity with 4 terms) commute on the nose, and not just up to isomorphism. So, can we define the derived tensor product in a suitable way so that the pentagon diagram will commute on the nose?
2. Assuming the answer to 1 is yes, is this also a closed monoidal category? Again, we have an obvious candidate for internal hom, that is: $RHom_A(-,-)$. But we have a problem: morphisms in $D(A)$ are only $H^0(RHom_A(-,-))$, and it follows from the axioms of a symmetric monoidal category that the internal hom and the hom are isomorphic as sets. So, can this be fixed in any sensible way?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "up to isomorphism"? I don't see any $2$-categorical structure on $D(A)$ (actually this has been modded out in its construction). What makes you think that the pentagon diagram doesn't commute?

Comment: 1. Well, I don't really mean anything. I just wanted to say that the diagram should commute. Bad wording. 2. I do not know if it commutes. Hence, the question.

Comment: Here is an additional thought, at least for $D^{-}(A)$: replace it with $K^{-}(A)_{proj}$, that is bounded above complexes of projectives. On that category we can define a monoidal structure, and then use the inclusion to induce such a structure on $D^{-}(A)$. Maybe that will work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hovey has proved the following general result:

> **Theorem.** If $\mathcal{M}$ is a (symmetric) monoidal model category, then $\operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{M}$ is a (symmetric) monoidal closed category under the derived tensor product.

The category of unbounded chain complex of $A$-modules is a symmetric monoidal model category where the weak equivalences are the quasi-isomorphisms and the monoidal product is the Koszul tensor product. Thus the derived category is a symmetric monoidal closed category under the derived tensor product. The details can be found in Chapter 4 of [Hovey, *Model categories*].

Comment: Thanks. This does answer my first question, but I still don't understand what is the answer to the second question. Does an element of $RHom(M,N)$ defines a morphism from $M$ to $N$ in any sensible way?

Comment: What is "an element" of $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}(M, N)$? This is only well-defined up to quasi-isomorphism. But you can certainly talk about $H^0 (\mathbf{R} \mathrm{Hom}(M, N))$, though.

Comment: Why? I mean, there is a bifunctor $RHom:D(A)\times D(A)\to D(A)$, right? and any element of $D(A)$ is a complex, and in particular a set.

Comment: Well, you seem to be taking "is" in a very literal sense there. The objects in a category need not be sets of any kind, so your claim about "elements" in a monoidal closed category cannot possibly be true. The correct statement is that there is a natural bijection between morphisms $I \to [A, B]$ and morphisms $A \to B$, where $I$ is the monoidal unit and $[A, B]$ is the internal hom.

Comment: So is there an internal hom on $D(A)$? Is the statement you now wrote true for $RHom$?

Comment: Yes, the derived category is a symmetric monoidal closed category, as I stated above. The internal hom is $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}$, and there is a natural bijection between morphisms $I \to C$ (in the derived category) and $H^0 (C)$.